# how to setup blogs under a page

Tags: wordpress

I have a wordpress site setup tradepeacefully.com
i have postings that appear on the home page. I want postings under trades menu link

http://tradepeacefully.com/?page_id=27

how can i do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create tow pages called "home" and "Trade" leave these blank then
Go to Settings > Reading. 
Set 'Front page displays:' to 'a static page' and choose the first page you created above for 'Front page.' set 'Posts page' to the page "trade" you created above.
for more info please follow [link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to have this happen in WP is to not have your Trades page as a page. Use a category instead, which is usually setup to handle posts.